# How to create a list containing random pairs from an original list?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a list:

```
lst = ['ab', 'cd','ef', 'gh', 'ij', 'mn', 'op', 'qr', 'st', 'uv', 'wx', 'yz']
```

I would like to take 2 random values from this list and put them in to a new list as pairs until the original list is empty.

For example:

new_list = [('ab', 'ef'), ('ij', 'yz') exc. ]
lst = []

How can I do this using a while and for loop?

I've tried using this method to generate a random pair from the list:

```
random_lst = random.randint(0,len(lst)-1)
```

However I'm not sure how to remove the values from the original lsit and then add them to the new list as pairs.

Comment: Do you actually need the original list to become empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```python
import random

lst = ['ab', 'cd','ef', 'gh', 'ij', 'mn', 'op', 'qr', 'st', 'uv', 'wx', 'yz']
new_list = []

for i in range(len(lst)//2):
    # Get a random index in the current list
    idx = random.randint(0,len(lst)-1)
    # Remove the respective element and store it
    element1 = lst.pop(idx)
    # Get another random index in the current list
    idx = random.randint(0,len(lst)-1)
    # Remove and store that element as well
    element2 = lst.pop(idx)
    # Create an entry (tuple) in the final list
    new_list.append((element1, element2))

print(new_list)
```

The output for me is `[('yz', 'ij'), ('wx', 'ab'), ('st', 'cd'), ('gh', 'uv'), ('qr', 'ef'), ('op', 'mn')]`

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are lots of ways. Here's a simple one.

```
lst = ['ab', 'cd','ef', 'gh', 'ij', 'mn', 'op', 'qr', 'st', 'uv', 'wx', 'yz']
result = []
random.shuffle(lst)
for i in range(0, len(lst), 2):
    result.append((lst[i], lst[i+1]))
```

Comment: not. work for odd no of items

Comment: Just put a `-1` after `len(lst)` in the for loop, then the last (odd) element will be ignored.

Comment: @sahasrara62 The question makes it sound like there will always be an even number.

Comment: @KellyBundy it's better to take precautions :)

Comment: OP would have to clarify what to do with an odd number. Leave it out or make a tuple with just one item?

Comment: @sahasrara62 They say "take 2 until empty". How do you do that when you start with an odd number?

Comment: @KellyBundy yeah, my bad, wrong assusmption by me, it need to be specified by OP clearly in question if there are cases for odd no of element or not

Answer (score 0):

The *sample()* function from the *random* module is ideal for this

```
from random import sample as SAMPLE

lst = ['ab', 'cd','ef', 'gh', 'ij', 'mn', 'op', 'qr', 'st', 'uv', 'wx', 'yz']
output = []

while lst:
    output.append(SAMPLE(lst, min(2, len(lst))))
    for e in output[-1]:
        lst.remove(e)

print(output)
```

**Note:**

*min()* function is essential for the case where the input list contains an odd number of elements

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of approaches.
With your method, you could try:

```py
import random
lst = ['ab', 'cd','ef', 'gh', 'ij', 'mn', 'op', 'qr', 'st', 'uv', 'wx', 'yz']
random_lst = []
while lst:
  random_lst.append((lst.pop(random.randint(0,len(lst)-1)), lst.pop(random.randint(0,len(lst)-1))))

print(random_lst)
```

A slight modification to be a bit faster would be:

```py
import random
lst = ['ab', 'cd','ef', 'gh', 'ij', 'mn', 'op', 'qr', 'st', 'uv', 'wx', 'yz', 'xr']
random_lst = []
random.shuffle(lst)
while lst:
  random_lst.append((lst.pop(), lst.pop()))

print(random_lst)
```

This example accounts for odd length of lists:

```py
import random
lst = ['ab', 'cd','ef', 'gh', 'ij', 'mn', 'op', 'qr', 'st', 'uv', 'wx', 'yz', 'xr']
random_lst = []
random.shuffle(lst)
while lst:
  if len(lst) == 1:
    # The list is not even
    random_lst.append(lst.pop())
    break
  random_lst.append((lst.pop(), lst.pop()))

print(random_lst)
```

Check out the results: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19gwP5zPGPXXjGx1AR6VjNkXIIqa16oep#scrollTo=ySBobtc3rtsj

If you want to work with larger lists, I'll suggest checking out [numpy](https://numpy.org/).

Answer (score -1):

You can try something using [`np.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```
new_list = []

while lst:
    tmp=np.random.choice(lst, 2).tolist()
    for t in tmp:
        lst.remove(t)
    new_list.append(tmp)
    
print(new_list)

[['op', 'wx'], ['yz', 'cd'], ['ef', 'qr'], ['mn', 'ij'], ['uv', 'gh'], ['ab', 'st']]
```